# How do I dictate the order of preferred replica on a Always On cluster?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have a problem, I look after a massive estate. the newer AO clusters I built myself and they work fine. I have inherited once AO cluster which is often problematic. However, migrating isn't an option ATM.

My current problem is I notice Netbackup wouldn't take backups from the secondary. After investigation, I found it was trying to take the backup from the DR instance. I've set it to take from the Primary for now.

Current behaviour

```
AUTOMATED_BACKUP_PREFERENCE = PRIMARY
```

preferred replica results

DR = 0

primary = 1

secondary = 0

```
AUTOMATED_BACKUP_PREFERENCE = SECONDARY_ONLY
```

preferred replica results

DR = 1

primary =  0

secondary = 0

The behaviour I need it to be is how can I get it to be,

```
AUTOMATED_BACKUP_PREFERENCE = SECONDARY_ONLY
```

preferred replica results

DR = 0

primary =  0

secondary = 1

However I can't find anything on Microsoft to point me in the right direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the backup Priority to be higher on your non-DR node

[image]

By curiosity, why are you taking backup on the secondaries ?

There is some cases where your secondary could be out of sync with the primary (even if you set you AG to by Sync), for that reason, I usually prefer to have my backup done on my primary node.

Also, if you take the backup on the secondary node, are you also running checkdb on that secondary node ? (you don't want to end up doing backup of a corrupted secondary)

Comment: Arh ok! cheers mate! I'll try that tomorrow! I'm safe for now. But if that works I'll set it across the estate.

Comment: That worked a treat! thank you every so much :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Again, be carefull if offloading your backup on secondary site as it comes with some gotcha ;)

Comment: RE your question: "why are you taking backup on the secondaries?"
I wish I could! I have also seen issues with the way I've been told to set this up. We have lost the secondary and NetBackup has gone to the DR (the other secondary) means the backup stop, Inturn the transaction logs fill up down Instance. Whereas if we took from the primary Netbackup would handle it, customers would be fine with me doing some remedial work. However my Lead DBA and Manager, he is adamant this is how he wants it. I haven't been told why, and as such I'm taking ownership of my personal development :)